# Disallow column dragging to certain positions with ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have 5 columns on my grid, and I want to disallow users to be able to drag the columns on the right of the middle column to the left, and same goes disallow columns on the left dragged to the right.

My fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/10ei

I have a column called No Crossing Zone, how I can disallow `id` and `name` from dragged to the right side of the `No Crossing Zone`, and disable `Group 1` and `Group 2` to the left side of the `No Crossing Zone`?

I can add any new key:value pairs to the data set if needed.

Answer (score 1):

With this code, the column right of the `No Crossing Zone` will be moved back right of it if it is moved left of it. And vise versa:

1st solution:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            columns: [
            {
                text: 'Id'

            },
            {
                text: 'Name'
            },
            {
                text: 'No Crossing Zone',
                draggable: false
            }, 
            {
                text: 'Group 1',
            }, 
            {
                text: 'Group 2',

            }],

            listeners:{
                columnmove: function (ct, column, fromIdx, toIdx, eOpts) {
                    var noCrossCol = undefined,
                        crossCol = undefined,
                        i = 0;
                    Ext.each(ct.getGridColumns(), function(col) { // There may be a better way to get "crossColIdx" and "crossCol"...
                        if(col.text == 'No Crossing Zone') {
                            crossColIdx = i;
                            crossCol = col;
                            return false;
                        }
                        i++;
                    });
                    console.log("fromIdx: " + fromIdx + "; toIdx: " + toIdx);
                    if((fromIdx <= crossColIdx) && (toIdx > crossColIdx)) {
                        console.log("moved too far");
                        ct.moveBefore(column, crossCol);
                    }
                    if((fromIdx >= crossColIdx) && (toIdx < crossColIdx)) {
                        console.log("moved too near");
                        ct.moveAfter(column, crossCol);
                    }
                }
            },

            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        })
    }
});
```

Second solution:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            columns: [{
                text: 'left part',
                sealed: true,
                columns: [{
                    text: 'Id'
                }, {
                    text: 'Name',
                    sealed: true,
                    columns: [{
                        text: 'Sub 1'
                    }, {
                        text: 'Sub 2'
                    }]
                }]
            }, {
                text: 'No Crossing Zone',
                draggable: false
            }, {
                text: 'right part',
                sealed: true,
                columns: [{
                    text: 'Group 1',
                    sealed: true,
                    columns: [{
                        text: 'Sub 1'
                    }, {
                        text: 'Sub 2'
                    }]
                }, {
                    text: 'Group 2',
                    sealed: true,
                    columns: [{
                        text: 'Sub 1'
                    }, {
                        text: 'Sub 2'
                    }]
                }]
            }],
            flex: 1,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        })
    }
});
```

You could even delete the `No Crossing Zone` column.
(Edited after request in the comments)

Comment: Hey @Michel FRANKE Thank you very much for the help, I have one important question, is it possible to use the solution with sub headers added: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/10ei  . I still want to be able to only apply the drag zone rules to ID, Name, and Group 1 and Group 2. As for the sub groups, they shouldnt be affected, as they will be sealed. Can you take a look at the fiddle?

Comment: Do you use ExtJS5 or ExtJS6? (Your first fiddle was with V6 and this one with V5... I'm a bit confused)

Comment: Yeah I thought about just make a super header for both sections and make it sealed. But I really wanted to avoid it, is it possible to hide the Right Part and Left Part headers completelty so it doesnt show? Either with CSS or ExtJS? I tried set hidden to true for Right Part and Left part, but they hide all the children headers as well.. so that doesnt work

Comment: And what about setting its height to 0?